# Sails app doesn't lower

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In a custom script, I'm lifting Sails, doing some stuff, then calling `.lower()` but the app doesn't stop. No error is returned either...

```
const Sails = require('sails')
  , rc = require('rc');

function run() {
  Sails.lift(rc('sails', {process: 'manual'}), (err, server)=> {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

     // ... do some stuff

      Sails.lower({}, (err)=> {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
        return true;
      }); 
    });
  });
}
```

The app just continues running. No error is returned from `.lower()` and it doesn't have a callback result by default. I debugged in the `lower.js` file itself and turns out that that code isn't even reached...

I think the problem is that `lower()` returns a callback, but my script doesn't accept one, so how do I manage this case?

Comment: Hope you are calling only on err right. Try adding a console.log to check after the lowering.

OR 

Add Sails Callback to check when lowering is complete.

Comment: @Thennarasan, I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, actually the app was getting lowered and all services (HTTP, socket, etc.) were shut down, but the process itself continued running. `process.exit()` was the solution. So, I first gracefully lower all services and then terminate the process:

```
      Sails.lower({}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          log.error('An error occurred while shutting the server down.');
        }
        process.exit();
      });
```